# How to save/pass MongoDB UpdateDefinition for logging and later use?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb

**I am stumped on how to save/pass MongoDB UpdateDefinition for logging and later use**

I have created general functions for MongoDB in Azure use on a collection for get, insert, delete, update that work well.

The purpose is to be able to have a standard, pre-configured way to interact with the collection. For update especially, the goal is to be able to flexibly pass in an appropriate UpdateDefinition where that business logic is done elsewhere and passed in.

I can create/update/set/combine the UpdateDefinition itself, but when i try to log it by serializing it, it shows null:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateDef)
```

When I try to log it, save it to another a class or pass it to another function it displays null:

```
public class Account
    {
        [BsonElement("AccountId")]
        public int    AccountId     { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Email")]
        public string Email         { get; set; }
    }

var updateBuilder = Builders<Account>.Update;
var updates = new List<UpdateDefinition<Account>>();

//just using one update here for brevity - purpose is there could be 1:many depending on fields updated
updates.Add(updateBuilder.Set(a => a.Email, email));

//Once all the logic and field update determinations are made
var updateDef = updateBuilder.Combine(updates);

//The updateDef does not serialize to string, it displays null when logging.
_logger.LogInformation("{0} - Update Definition: {1}", actionName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateDef));

//Class Created for passing the Account Update Information for Use by update function
public class AccountUpdateInfo
    {
        [BsonElement("AccountId")]
        public int                          AccountId   { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("Update")]
        public UpdateDefinition<Account>    UpdateDef   { get; set; }
    }

var acct = new AccountUpdateInfo();
acctInfo.UpdateDef = updateDef

//This also logs a null value for the Update Definition field when the class is serialized.
_logger.LogInformation("{0} - AccountUpdateInfo: {1}", actionName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(acct));
```

Any thoughts or ideas on what is happening?  I am stumped on why I cannot serialize for logging or pass the value in a class around like I would expect

Comment: What "shows null"? Where? Have you tried debugging it? Please post an [mcve].

Comment: It looks to be that if the UpdateDefinition isn't immediately used by UpdateOneAsync(filter, update) then the value is lost

Comment: The value when it has been logged.  I have added/updated the two logging statements where it logs a null value when Serialized for logging.

One directly when trying to serialize UpdateDefinition to string for logging.
The second when trying to serialize a class that has the value for logging.

Comment: Why in the world would someone down vote the question?  It is a completely reasonable and legit question and if it is obvious they should give an answer.

Answer (score 4):

give this a try:

```cs
var json = updateDef.Render(
               BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<Account>(),
               BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry)
           .AsBsonDocument
           .ToString();
```

and to turn a json string back to an update definition (using implicit operator), you can do:

```cs
UpdateDefinition<Account> updateDef = json;
```

this is off the top of my head and untested. the only thing i'm unsure of (without an IDE) is the `.Document.ToString()` part above.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try for the logging.

Comment: Awesome!!  That worked great for the first part of being able to make the UpdateDefinition loggable as a string.  Many thanks.  Off the top of your head that was impressive.  The only thing that needed changing was I replaced ".Document" with ".AsBsonDocument" for it to work.

Comment: For the second part - I will see if I can pass the json string value between functions, as the UpdateDefinition itself was failing to pass and use the reverse as you have listed.

Comment: The second part, passing the json string around, as opposed to the UpdateDefinition itself worked really well! Was able to set it to the UpdateDefinition exactly as specified when it was needed to do the update.  Still not sure why he UpdateDefinition itself was failing to pass around.  Passing string around is cludgey I know, but it does work and make sense. Thanks @Đĵ ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ !!

Comment: @drewid the c# mongo driver is quite a complex piece of machinery. i've been battling with it for over a year trying to build a [wrapper library](https://mongodb-entities.com/) over it and some stuff just stuck with me i guess :-)